# Get source code for a specific page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The code below displays the source code of the current page:

Website as example: http://jsfiddle.net/635YY/1/

```
var url="../635YY",xmlhttp;//Remember, same domain
if("XMLHttpRequest" in window)xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
if("ActiveXObject" in window)xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
xmlhttp.open('GET',url,true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
};
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

How to display the source code of another page (other than the current page)?

Comment: unless you are supporting an ancient browser forget about `ActiveXObject`

Comment: So set the url to the page you want to reference.....

Comment: That request is **not** going to current page

Comment: @epascarello How to do this?

Comment: @charlietfl I want it to be a different domain. Example: url="https://stackoverflow.com"

Comment: Will probably need to use a proxy due to CORS restrictions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
url="/about";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {

  alert( this.responseXML.documentElement.innerHTML );

}
xhr.open( 'GET', url );
xhr.responseType = 'document';
xhr.send();
```

Unfortunately you will not be able to do this with pages on another website unless the CORS policy on the website allows it, or you will get an error like

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://test.com/' from origin 'http://jsfiddle.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```